# PYTHON - Implementação de Sequência de Fibonacci

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Estou tentando colocar a sequência de Fibonacci em Python no VSCode, e toda vez que tento rodar o seguinte código, aparece o erro:

```
line 8, in <module>
    Fibonacci[i] = proximo
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como consertar ?

```
Fibonacci = [0]*100
anterior = 0
proximo = 1
i = 0


while (i <= 100):
    Fibonacci[i] = proximo
    proximo = proximo + anterior
    anterior = proximo - anterior
    i = i + 1


print(Fibonacci)
```

Comment: `Fibonacci.append(proximo)`

Comment: Vale lembrar que em Python listas são dinâmicas e podem aumentar/diminuir de tamanho conforme a necessidade, então não precisa criar a lista com 100 valores artificiais no início, bastaria fazer assim: https://ideone.com/ARLpBG

Answer (score 1):

Você está cometendo um erro clássico de *off-by-one* (erro-de-um).

`while (i <= 100):` irá fazer você acessar até o valor `Fibonacci[100]`, o qual não existe - os valores para a lista foram inicializados nas posições de 0 a 99.

Simplesmente troque por `while (i < 100):` e seu código deverá rodar.

Comment: Valeu demais! Deu certo!